# How can we understand the word God אלהים (H430)in exodus 7:1?

Tags: word-study, exodus

Exodus 7:1 (NKJV)

> 1 So the LORD said to Moses: “See, I have made you  as **God** to  Pharaoh, and Aaron your brother shall be your prophet.

In what context was the author of exodus using this noun?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elsewhere in the Book of Exodus, the noun אֱלֹהִים is used in reference to human judges.<sup>1</sup> For example, in Exo. 21:6, it is written,

> <sup>6</sup> Then his master shall bring him unto **the judges** (**הָאֱלֹהִים**); he shall also bring him to the door, or unto the door post; and his master shall bore his ear through with an aul; and he shall serve him for ever. <sup>KJV, 1769</sup>

Human judges are referred to as אֱלֹהִים because הַמִּשְׁפָּט לֵאלֹהִים—“judgment is Yahveh’s.”<sup>2</sup> Hence, King Jehoshaphat informed the judges, “You do not judge for man, but for Yahveh, who is with you in the matter of judgment.”<sup>3</sup> Accordingly, Yahveh appoints (or “makes”) Moses an אֱלֹהִים or “judge” over Pharaoh because Yahveh was going to use Moses in order to execute judgments upon Egypt.

In Exo. 7:4, it is written,

> <sup>4</sup> But Pharaoh shall not hearken unto you, that I may lay my hand upon Egypt, and bring forth mine armies, and my people the children of Israel, out of the land of Egypt by great judgments. <sup>KJV, 1769</sup>

According to Carl Friedrich Keil,<sup>4</sup>

> Moses was a god to Aaron as the revealer of the divine will, and to Pharaoh as the executor of that will.

---

### References

Keil, Carl Friedrich. [*Commentary on the Old Testament.*](https://archive.org/details/biblicalcommenta00keil01) 1900. Reprint. Trans. Martin, James. Vol. 1. Grand Rapids: Eerdmans, 1986.

### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> Exo. 21:6, 22:8–9
<sup>2</sup> Deu. 1:17
<sup>3</sup> 2 Chr. 19:6
<sup>4</sup> p. [472](https://archive.org/stream/biblicalcommenta00keil01#page/n474/mode/1up)

Comment: @Chin-Lee Chan  The above is a good example of how a human can be called God (elohim) because he stands in for God as Judge and Law giver to his people, Israel, so Godlike is his power that he can also carry out death sentence for gross Law breakers on God's behalf, like God having the power of life and dearth in thier hands  This is a fine example of "elohim" being used in a generic sense and not a literal sense.   The same with the other texts I  sent to you,